Handling download and installation of transitive dependencies for my custom python package
I need suggestions on how on to handle download and installation of transitive dependencies for my custom python package.
I have designed a package called 'helloWorld'.
My helloWorld package has direct dependency on 2 packages: Package A and Package B.
Package A has dependency on Numpy==w and Pandas==x, and package B has dependency on Pandas==y (y>x) and matplotlib==z. Both package A and B, along with dependent packages are hosted on my artifact library, URL of which I am passing with --index-url when downloading/installing requirements for helloWorld.
I have created *.whl file of helloWorld and uploaded it on same Artifact library, from where my colleagues can download and use this (helloWorld) package.
When my colleagues are downloading .whl file of helloWorld and installing it, they want all direct and transitive dependencies to be auto-installed along with main package. Or at least they should get a list of all (direct and transitive) dependencies in a requirements file packed in the .whl file so that they could download dependencies as well.
The .whl file only contains code and details of setup.py file for my helloWorld package, and doesn't include any detail about direct or transitive dependencies.
How to handle this?
I used pip-tools to generate detailed requirements.txt file from requirements.in file when I was developing helloWorld package. And used pip wheel . to create the .whl file for the helloWorld package.

Wheel files include details about direct dependencies in the file *.dist-info/METADATA; see the header(s) Requires-Dist:. It doesn't include details about transitive dependencies; the only way for pip to get recursive dependencies is to download dependencies recursively: download direct dependencies of named packages, then download theirs direct dependencies, then download direct dependencies deeper and so on until the lists of direct dependencies are exhausted.
